# Disable deleting application by tap-and-hold

Tags: ios

Usually on a long press of a third-party application icon, it will give you the option to delete the app. Is there any way to disable that option, the way it seems to be with the preloaded applications on iPhone?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to do it from within the app.

You could, however, configure the parental settings on the device to disallow removing applications (Settings -> General -> Restrictions), but you would need to do it on each device you want the feature enabled, and the setting will apply for all third party apps, not only yours.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't disable it. If you're developing some enterprise application where the iPad is supposed to run only your app and nothing else, I suggest getting a case or something along those lines to block the "home" button on the iPad.